# How to make apk file from aab file

Tags: android, react-native, cmd, apk

I am trying to make an apk of my react native app folder. I followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cws_eQ5LQUk&t=420s tutorial but the resultant file turned out to be app.aab file.

So how can I make it an apk file from this and installed it in another emulator?

Comment: You want to make release apk to play store?

Comment: yes, I want to make it a release apk file

Comment: I suggest to use aab file to release app to playstore.Because it will create many different versions of app based on chip architecture, screen size and locale

Answer (score 0):

There is a good [step-by-step tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) in react documentation.

You have to generate a signed apk file for publishing to Google Play Store. It can be done by following command. But first, you have to generate an upload key and set up gradle variables, check the link above.

```
$ cd android
$ ./gradlew bundleRelease
```

Comment: I followed each step of it. but in the end, it is generating aab file

Comment: It should be under `/android/app/build/outputs/apk`, isn't it?

Comment: according to the site, it is in `android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab` and I found aab file there.

Comment: in `/android/app/build/outputs/apk` there is `app-debug.apk` not `app-release.apk`

Comment: After I followed all the spets `app-release.apk` is under `/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release`.

Also, try to run gradlew clean before build. `cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease`.

Comment: BTW, which version of react-native do you use?

Comment: 0.59.8 react native version

Comment: If you are letting Google manage the release signing, you can just create an upload signing keystore and produce an `.aab` file. If you want to manage signing completely yourself you can use an `.apk` or `.aab` I believe.