# How to convert. APK file to .AAB file?

Tags: java, android

How to convert. APK file to .AAB file?
Even if it is irrelavant to your field, Please do share this to your friends who are expert in android app development.
I would be thankful for all your valuable responses

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57934077/how-to-make-apk-file-from-aab-file

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are able to build the APK from source. You need to run task `bundle<VariantName>` instead of `assemble<VariantName>` (or in Android Studio run `Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build Bundle(s)`.